# Overlay Asset Action bar's 'properties' button

Tags: overlay, aem, assets

I want to overlay the 'properties' button in the action bar of File console under Asset, but I don't know the location of the required node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to overlay here :

/apps/dam/gui/content/assets/jcr:content/actions/selection

Comment: under selection viewProperties node exists for Properties button in Asset page, I have overlayed it, and i want to get an alert on the click of the Properties button. where should I add my client library file?

Comment: This is different question, please first accept it and create another one, I will respond  to it